# SSIS DevOps Tools > sample JSON for SSIS Catalog Configuration Task is throwing error

Tags: azure-devops, ssis

I installed the [SSIS DevOps Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.ssis-devops-tools) in my Azure DevOps instance so I can use Pipelines & Release to build SSIS Projects on my on-premises self-hosted agent (SHA) and deploy them to my on-premises SQL Server that has an SSISDB Catalog setup.

I am testing out the SSIS Catalog Configuration Task which is supposed to allow me to create folders (and projects and environments) in my SSIS Catalog before I attempt to deploy my SSIS Projects to it and I am running into errors I cannot decipher.

I am trying to get the [sample JSON Microsoft provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-overview?view=sql-server-2017#a-sample-inline-configuration-json) working however I am running into this error:

> ##[error][Folder: devopsdemo] Failed to create the folder 'devopsdemo': Operation 'Create' on object
> 'CatalogFolder[@Name='devopsdemo']' failed during execution..

Does anyone have a working example they can share?

Note that I have setup a PowerShell Script Task in my Release that calls a Catalog Procedure to setup a folder in the SSIS Catalog and it was successful so I know the Catalog is online and that my service account has permissions to create folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following changes on your SQL Server to fix the issue, the try to create the Catalog folder again:

- Enable **`Trustworthy`** database property.

  ```sql
  ALTER DATABASE [SSISDB Name] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
  ```
- Change the database owner to '**`sa`**'.

  ```sql
  ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE ::[SSISDB Name] TO sa;
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I tried both of these things but it made no difference.

Comment: @OrlandoColamatteo, On the **SSIS Catalog Configuration** Task, try to use the credentials that when you sign in the SSIS DB from the on-premises server.

Comment: My SSIS Catalog Configuration Task is configured to use Windows Authentication. I am confident the Windows Account used has the necessary permissions because I setup a PowerShell Script Task in the pipeline that runs using Windows Authentication that uses the Catalog Stored Procedures to create a new Folder and it was successful. 

It's when running using the SSIS Catalog Configuration Task that I encounter the error in the original post. 

My next attempt is to setup an Extended Events session to capture the exact SQL the SSIS Catalog Configuration Task ends up issuing to the server.